# Firefox has stopped saving all passwords and usernames, why?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, security

ff will not save passwords for any site and all passwords i had saved are gone.

I have checked that it is set to save passwords and checked everything I could find on the internet.
How can I get them back?

Answer (score 0):

First, the safest way to recover passwords is from your last backup or disk image. Barring that, you could try the following:

- [Start Firefox in Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and typing

  > firefox -safe-mode

  to see if the passwords are visible. If so:
- [Refresh Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings) to remove any extension that might be causing an issue.
- [*Password Exporter*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/password-exporter/) might be able to recover them, and, even better, export them. If that works, I'd suggest encrypting the list, and keeping it elsewhere than on the PC.
- Nirsoft's [PasswordFox](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/passwordfox.html) can bypass Firefox and recover user names and passwords from your profile. Note that this *is* a useful forensic tool, but is considered a PUP (probably undesired program) by many anti-malware suites because of potential misuse by miscreants. If you override your AV warning and use it, you might still wish to delete it afterwards, to avoid *others* trying it.
- Finally, your passwords are stored in the [key3.db and logins.json files in your profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data). If there is a backup of these files somewhere, perhaps you can restore them (after saving the *current* files to another location.

See [Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-and-import) for more information on *Password Manager*.

Of great concern is that you've lost the ability to save or view passwords. This could be due to malware, a broken profile, a duplicated profile or other causes.

Scan your PC, and browsers, in particular, for malware. After you're satisfied the PC is safe to use, if Refresh does not resolve the issue, then go to the Firefox menu item *Bookmarks | Show All Bookmarks* and Backup (export) your bookmarks. Then [delete your profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) and create a new one. Import the saved passwords and bookmarks from the steps above.

Comment: Welcome... did it resolve the issue?